# HAProxy & WordPress in subdirectory — login into wp-admin redirects to root

Tags: haproxy, wordpress

I have two VPS running. One is running HAProxy and another one is running WordPress. Both VPS has private networking enabled and I can `curl` the WordPress site fine from HAProxy server using its private IP address.

Here is URL settings for my WordPress site:

[image]

The HAProxy is doing SSL termination in this case because I'm planning to install more WordPress sites later with the following URLs:

- my-website.com/blog (WordPress #1)
- my-website.com/foo  (WordPress #2)
- my-website.com/bar  (WordPress #3)

Here is my config for HAProxy.

```
global
  # default global config goes here
  maxconn 2048
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client  50000
  timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth xxx:xxx

frontend my-wordpress-frontend
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/my-website.com.pem
  option http-server-close
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  acl blog path_beg /blog
  acl wpadmin path_beg /wp-
  acl blog_search query -m reg ^s=.*$
  acl blog_preview query -m reg ^p=.*$
  acl root path /
  redirect location https://my-website.com/blog/ if root
  use_backend my-wordpress-backend if blog OR blog wpadmin OR blog blog_search OR blog blog_preview
  default_backend my-wordpress-backend

backend my-wordpress-backend
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /blog/(.*) \1\ /\2
   reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /blog/wp-admin/(.*) \1\ /\2
   cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
   server www-1 private_ip_address:80 check cookie
```

Everything looks fine except one thing. I'm able to see the login page at `https://my-website.com/blog/wp-login.php`. But, after I login, it redirects me to `https://my-website.com/wp-admin`.

This is not what I want. I was expecting to get `https://my-website.com/blog/wp-admin`.

I added this to *my wp-config.php* but it didn't help:

```
// Start custom config ---
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
// End custom config ---

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Did I miss something here? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You configured the WordPress base URL with `https://example.com/`. You should be able to go manually to `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/` after logging in. Then configure the base URL properly (`https://example.com/blog/`) in the general settings of WordPress.

If that doesn't work you can manually configure the URL in the database, the setting is in the table `wp_options`.

Comment: I changed it but the problem persists. See this - https://i.imgur.com/SGWMj1Y.png

Comment: well then look through the database if you find the wrong URL referenced anywhere. You spare yourself a lot of work if you set up WordPress using the URL you want to use it finally.